# Delete a value from Php Comma seperated value array saved in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have a script which works great for saving users in comma seperated value to MySQL 'reserve' field.

eg '510,465,8552'

I then have the script below which echos the users name from the comma seperated 'reserve' field.
The bit i am struggling with is to be able to click on a delete image next to one of the users and it will delete the users id from the comma seperated value.

```
    $entries = get_records_sql ("SELECT * FROM development ORDER BY pdorder ASC");  
    foreach($entries as $lesson) {

    $waiting = explode(",", $lesson->reserve);
    foreach($waiting as $unlucky) {
    $reserveuser = get_record("user", "id", $unlucky);

    if($reserveuser->id>1){
echo '<li id="lstno'.$lesson->id.'" name="'.$reserveuser->id.'">'.$reserveuser->firstname.'&nbsp;'.$reserveuser->lastname.' ';
echo '<a href="removereserve.php?id='.$lesson->id.'&reserve='.$reserveuser->id.'"><img title="unenrol" src="delete.gif" /></a>';
        echo '</li>';
        }
    }
```

Any guidance would be much appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you storing user ids in a comma-separated field?  Anyways, just get the record and use string manipulation to remove the substring and update the database with the new value

Comment: After exploding you can just unset the part of the array you wish to delete, then implode the array to a string again and update the database with the new string

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, if all of the user id's are saved in one field my approach would be something like this http://codepad.org/KTAJ3ROb

Hope that helps figuring it out!

Comment: This contain some bug try with a value that not exists in the list it will remove first one. ?? you should use in_array first for checking that then only unset().

Answer (score 1):

This is probably **bad database design**, unless you know what you are doing.

The one way to delete just one value is to read whole cell, remove it with php and write it back.

```
$waiting = explode(",", $lesson->reserve);
//delete desired one
unset($waiting[3]);
//implode it back
$store = implode(',', $waiting);
mysql_query("UPDATE table SET reserve='$store'");
```

If comma separated IDs are unique (you dont have say **11**,20,**11**), then you can use mysql `REPLACE` function.

```
mysql_query("UPDATE table SET
reserve=REPLACE(reserve, ',$oldid', ',$newid'),
reserve=REPLACE(reserve, '$oldid,', '$newid,')");
```

There is a litle trick involved to specially handle first and last value.

Comment: what is "bad database design"? If referential integrity is not (so) important than a comma seperatetd list might be a good way to avoid a 'join' and speed up the db-query. Also ther are some databases (No-SQL) that do not support referential integrity...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make it directly in SQL (MySQL) then you can do it like this:

```
UPDATE ... SET USERS = TRIM(REPLACE(' ' + USERS + ' ', ' 7 ', ' '))
```

This will delete the user with the ID 7. The separator is not a ',' but a ' ' (blank). The Problem is, there is no function for removing ',' at the beginning or end like TRIM() for blanks.

Or you have to accept always a leading and tailing ',' in the USERS-field and do it like this:

```
UPDATE ... SET USERS = REPLACE(USERS, ',7,', ',')
```

Comment: I'm confused as to why this got a down-vote. This worked perfect for me! Thank you very much, exactly what i've been looking for.